# Using Different Methods for Input and Display of an Array

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop, methods

```
public class InputRealNums1
{
    static double [] numArr = new double [(int) (Math.random()*100)];
    static String res = "";
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        inputArray();
        displayArray();
    }

    static void inputArray()
    {
        for (int i = 0 ; i < numArr.length ; i++)
        {
            numArr[i] = Math.random()*100;
        }
    }

    static void displayArray()
    {
        System.out.println(res.inputArray());
    }
}
```

The aim of this code is to seperate the input and the output. The program would generate certain numbers and then it will display them. I just want to know how to seperate the the input and output with the above methods.

Comment: What do you mean by "seperate the the input and output with the above methods"

Comment: This program has no input or output, especially since it doesn't compile. Unclear what you're asking.

Comment: What do you think this is doing `res.inputArray()` didn't the compiler complain?

Comment: Figured problem out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can display that array by using this method.

```
public static void displayArray()
{
    for (int i = 0 ; i < numArr.length ; i++)
    {
        System.out.println(numArr[i]);
    }
}
```

But this is not a good way. You can do this by passing parameters to the method.

```
public static void displayArray(Double[] myArray)
{
    for (int i = 0 ; i < myArray.length ; i++)
    {
        System.out.println(myArray[i]);
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args){
    // some code in here
    displayArray(numArr);
}
```